# mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I’ve been trying to code a login form in PHP using a prepared statement but every time I try to log in I get the following error:

> mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root" , "" , "security");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username AND password FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$username = $_POST['name'];
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($password, $username);
$stmt->fetch();
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: You are binding 3 params and in your query there is only two.

Comment: Usually this happens, when you have query SELECT * and you add or remove field in table. using alter table.

Comment: It seems to me that you have a Typo in your SELECT clause -- `AND` should be a comma.

Answer (score 9):

```
$mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$username = $_POST['name'];
$stmt->bind_param('s' ,$username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
```

Your select syntax was wrong, the correct syntax is
`SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM TABLE WHERE field1 = ? AND field2 = ?`

To select more fields simply separate them by a comma and not an `AND`

Answer (score 3):

## Explanation

The error message clearly states that the number of columns you are `SELECT`ing does not match the number of variables you provided to [`mysqli_stmt::bind_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php). They need to match exactly.

For example:

```sql
--      ↓ 1   ↓ 2   ↓ 3
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tableA
```

There are 3 columns being fetched, so you need to provide 3 variables.

```
$stmt->bind_result($var1, $var2, $var3);
```

There could be a number of reasons why the column count doesn't match variable count.

## Count your columns and variables

The simplest cause is that you made a mistake in the count. Do a recount of both. Maybe you changed the SQL but forgot to adjust `bind_result()`?

## SELECT *

Using `SELECT *` is not recommended with `bind_result()`. The number of columns in the table could change as a result of schema changes or joins and will break your application. **Always list all the columns explicitly!**

## Logical problem with SQL

The code from the question contains a logical mistake. `SELECT username AND password` produces a single column in the result. The `AND` keyword evaluates to a boolean expression. To select multiple columns you must use `,`. Maybe there is another logical error in the query that causes the SQL to produce a different number of columns than you expected?

## UPDATE and INSERT

DML statements such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` do not produce result sets. You can't bind variables to such prepared statement. You need to execute another SELECT statement to fetch the data.

## Fetching an array from the prepared statement

The return value of `mysqli_stmt::bind_result()` is not an array, it's just a boolean. If you expected this function to return an array, then you are probably looking for `get_result()` with `fetch_all()` instead.

To select an array you need to get the `mysqli_result` object first.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username AND password FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$mysqli_result = $stmt->get_result();

// The object can then be iterated or used with fetch_* methods
foreach($mysqli_result as $row) {
}
// or
$arrayRow = $mysqli_result->fetch_assoc();
```

If this function doesn't exist in your PHP installation, then it means you have PHP not installed properly. You need to either recompile it, or enable mysqlnd (e.g. in cPanel).

If you are only learning PHP, it would be much easier for you to learn [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.